# Density Ramsey theorems with explicit asymptotics

Tags: co.combinatorics, ramsey-theory, additive-combinatorics, effective-results

I wonder what interesting and non-trivial examples of density Ramsey theorems with explicit asymptotics are there?

I'm aware of two examples: [Szemerédi's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Szemer%C3%A9di%27s_theorem) and [density Hales-Jewett theorem](https://arxiv.org/abs/0910.3926).

Let me try to formalize what I mean by "density Ramsey theorems". I'm interested in statements of the following type: for every $k \in \mathbb{N}, \alpha > 0$ there exists $n_0 = n_0(k, \alpha)$ such that if we have a collection of $n \geq n_0$ objects, then whatever $\alpha n$ objects we take there are $k$ among them that form a "nice" structure. Collections and niceness are problem-specific of course: in case of Szemerédi's theorem they are $\lbrace 1, 2, \ldots, n\rbrace$ and arithmetic progressions, for Hales-Jewett — $[k]^d$ and combinatorial lines, respectively. I'm particularly interested in theorems where the dependence $n_0 = n_0(k, \alpha)$ can be made explicit.

Answer (score 11):

Fix $\epsilon>0$. Every subset $A$ of $\{1,2,\dots,n\}$ with $|A|\geq \epsilon n$ contains a centrally symmetric subset $E$ (in other words, there is a $c$ with $E-c=c-E$) with $|E|> \alpha \epsilon^2 n$. The optimal value for $\alpha$ isn't known, but there are reasonably close upper and lower bounds. [Greg Martin's paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/0807.5121), with some coauthor or other, isn't the state of the art, but it's the source that sticks in my mind.

Personally, I prefer the continuous statement: every subset of $[0,1]$ with measure $\epsilon$ contains a centrally symmetric subset with measure $0.6\epsilon^2$. And the the "$0.6$", while not best possible, cannot be replaced with "$0.9$".

Answer (score 2):

Kostas Tyros spoke in the Toronto set theory seminar just yesterday about a density version of the Halpern Lauchli Theorem. Actually he spoke about a finite version of the density theorem, and the density version is due to P. Dodos et. al. from 2010 I believe.

Answer (score 1):

A nice example is [Sárközy's theorem](http://alpha.math.uga.edu/%7Elyall/Research/Sarkozy.pdf) on squares among differences.